# NoSuchMethodError with Camel RouteDefinition class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-camel, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to debug a Java / Maven project with a lot of depencies on various libraries.
When I run it on a Linux server the program starts up fine, but when I try to run it in Eclipse it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.getErrorHandlerBuilder()Lorg/apache/camel/ErrorHandlerFactory;
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy.wrap(SpringTransactionPolicy.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.model.PolicyDefinition.createProcessor(PolicyDefinition.java:133)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:437)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:183)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:817)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:697)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1654)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1441)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1338)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1316)
```

Now, I can see that the RouteDefinition class is in the camel-core-2.9.3,jar and I can see that this library is imported. So how come it doesn't see that method?

How do I go about debugging this?

Could I get info from the process running on the Linux server? For example can I get the list of Jars that are imported and the order in which they are imported?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this library a direct dependency or second-hand?  If you look in your local repo is 2.9.3 the only copy?

Comment: Second-hand I guess. It's not in the pom.xml of my project, but it's inherited from some other project. In the Eclipse Maven Dependencies I have only 2.9.3, but if I look in the Maven repository on the disk I have many other versions (2.8.2, 2.9.5, etc.)

Comment: Try adding the correct version as a direct dependency in your pom, if you haven't already

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I get the same error. Do you think I can get any useful info out of the java process running fine on the Linux server?

Comment: Thanks Floegipoky. Deleting all versions from my local repo (except 2.9.3) did the trick. Still very annoyed with Eclipse that was telling me it was using that version, while in fact it was not!

Comment: The problem sounds like eclipse rather than maven. Have you tried rebuilding the eclipse project (mvn eclipse:eclipse or whatever it is these days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you're getting is caused by Maven pulling in the wrong version. Try deleting all versions out of your local repo, add it explicitly to your pom, clean out all of your builds, pray to the eclipse gods, etc. If it still gives you the error, check your local repo to see which wrong versions it pulled in, figure out what depends on them, and add explicit ignores for them while keeping the explicit include.